# Web3 error: "value out of bounds" when passing in value for smart contract call

Tags: web3js, javascript

When calling a function on a smart contract that takes a tokenID, I pass in the tokenID into web3 - but web3 then parses that string into another value it seems, pads it to the  left with a ton of zeros and then the contract call fails.

`tokenID: "5347359381416754638292106073567748474581852345025787828513953871505554409252111"`

```
export async function getTokenURI(address, tokenID) {
  try {
    console.log(address, typeof tokenID);
    return await getterContract(ABI, address, "tokenURI", [tokenID]);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(address, typeof tokenID);
    return "";
  }
}
```

```
export const getterContract = async (ABI, address, methodName, params) => {
  try {
    const contractInstance = await getDeployedContract(ABI, address);

    return await contractInstance.methods[methodName](...params)
      .call()
      .then((res) => {
        return res;
      });
  } catch (e) {
    throw e;
  }
};
```

Calling getTokenURI and passing in the token ID above - the actual value web3 is sending to the contract is:
`0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005347359381416754638292106073567748474581852345025787828513953871505554409252111`

Instead of the correct value of `5347359381416754638292106073567748474581852345025787828513953871505554409252111`

When passing in a smaller value such as `123456` it works fine.

Both values are passed into the function as strings - so not sure why the length of the string matters?

It seems to be converted or something since its padded to the left with a ton of zeros.

How to fix this?

Comment: What's the function signature in solidity? What's tokenID javascript type?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? if so how did you do it? I have the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is 'padded to the left with a ton of zeros' is because your return value represents a storage slot, so is represented in the total amount of bytes. With a quick check, I can affirm your getTokenURI return has 256 characters - so, this is a standard storage slot of 256 bytes; uint256.

To answer your initial question of why your contract call is failing, I'd have to know a bit more. What exactly do you mean when you say 'the contract fails'? Do you get errors? What errors do you get, if so?